# Specifying constants in VehicleStateCommand not working as expected

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the Lexus2016RXHybrid vehicle in the LGSVL simulator as described in [these instructions](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/lgsvl.html), along with the `lgsvl_interface` and `rosbridge.js` built from the 0.2.7 branch.

When sending this message on the CLI:

```
 ros2 topic pub /lgsvl/vehicle_state_cmd autoware_auto_msgs/msg/VehicleStateCommand "{blinker: 3}" --once
```

I was expecting the right blinker to flash since `uint8 BLINKER_RIGHT = 3`, but in fact the hazard lights flash.

Here is the message interface:

```
$ ros2 msg show autoware_auto_msgs/msg/VehicleStateCommand
# VehicleStateCommand.msg

builtin_interfaces/Time stamp
uint8 blinker 0
uint8 headlight 0
uint8 wiper 0
uint8 gear 0
uint8 mode 0
bool hand_brake false
bool horn false

### Definitions
# Blinker
uint8 BLINKER_NO_COMMAND = 0
uint8 BLINKER_OFF = 1
uint8 BLINKER_LEFT = 2
uint8 BLINKER_RIGHT = 3
uint8 BLINKER_HAZARD = 4
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347920/specifying-constants-in-vehiclestatecommand-not-working-as-expected/) by [tleyden2](https://answers.ros.org/users/52956/tleyden2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2020-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the report! As this bug is confirmed to exist, I've created an issue over on the Autoware.Auto Gitlab: https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/-/issues/384

Since we're currently working on making sure that interactions work correctly in the simulator, this should be addressed shortly.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1